# Convert to NSArray - iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, mkmapview

Is there a place where I can read up on this or maybe better to give me an example, how to change this code into an `NSArray`?

```
-(void)loadOurAnnotations
 {
 CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

 workingCoordinate.latitude = -37.711455;  //This has to be an integer 
 workingCoordinate.longitude = 176.285013; //This has to be an integer
 MyAnnotation *myLocation1 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate]; //The pointer has to be set to an array
[myLocation1 setTitle:@"The Palms Cafe"]; //The pointer and the setTitle here
[myLocation1 setSubtitle:@"157 Domain Road - (07) 542 2430"]; //The pointer and the setSubTitle here
[myLocation1 setAnnotationType:MyAnnotationTypeMine]; //again the pointer here

[mapView addAnnotation:myLocation1]; //and the pointer here

}
```

All of the pointers obviously come from the same place in the array and that whole piece of code (within the curly braces) is one record, so if I want to add another place i'll need to copy all of that again.

So what I am wanting to achieve is to set that up in a `Plist`, so that I can add the records in there, but only have the `-(void)loadOurAnnotations` be set once in the code and repeat itself. Of course if I should drop the `-(void)loadOurAnnotations` then that is not an issue, its just the way I have it at the moment.

As you may be able to tell by the info I gathering, these will be represented as an annotation on a `MKMapView`.

Any help is appreciated:-)

-Jeff

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. The Latitude and Longitude shouldn't be integers, they should be doubles (CLLocationDegrees). If you were to convert it to an integer, you would lose a lot of accuracy in the reading. What in particular do you want to set in an array? The method you've shown will constantly produce the same location. Are you trying to have this method return a `MyAnnotation` each time it is called, and then add that `MyAnnotation` to an array?

Comment: Oh I see - well what I want to achieve is to add more records like the one above which will then show as annotations on a map. then I need for the titles to show up in a tableview so that they can be selected by the user. I had a list of records, but they would all be put inside that void - so that could create a massive implementation file, Hence wanting to set them in a proper array and a plist. Hope this clarifies it?? CHeers -Jeff

Comment: I think `ubaltaci's` answer pretty much explains it. If you don't want to loop through them at once, as is done in the answer, you can change the signature of your `loadOutAnntations` method to allow parameters. This will allow you to do something like `loadOurAnnotations(lat,long,title,subtitle,annotationtype);`, replacing the parameters with the relevant information. In the method, it would then be `workingCoordinate.latitude = lat; workingCoordinate.longitude = long; etc..` This means you no longer have to keep copy/pasting the code, you can just call `loadOurAnnotations(...)` each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly,

First: you read your data from plist file into NSArray via some modal class. ( The example below "Location" just a modal class, and I fill in via core data )

```
// Location.h
@interface Location : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;

@end

// Location.h
@implementation Location

@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic name;

@end
```

Second: in your "loadOurAnnotations" method, iterate all values in "locationArray" which contains Location objects and for each Location object, I create PinLocation instance ( subclass of MkAnnotation ), and add them into mapView.

```
for(Location *location in locationArray) {
    NSString *name = [location name];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = [[location latitude] doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [[location longitude] doubleValue];

    PinLocation *pinLocation = [[PinLocation alloc] initWithName:name coordinate:coordinate];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pinLocation];      
}
```